# Make Heder & Mobile Menu Fixed On Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a site and I want my header and toggles fixed on mobile, Can anyone suggest me, how can I do it?

I tried positioning `fixed` but it didn't work, please suggest how can i do it.

```html
<div class="header">
                         
    <div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="togglemenuD"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/evotis1/images/info_menu.png" class="image_disp" height="20px" width="20px"></div>
    <div class="menu_nav">
    <ul>                                    
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-171" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-78 current_page_item menu-item-171"><a href="http://example.com/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-311" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-311"><a href="http://example.com/prijs-afsluiting.html">Prijs tuinafsluitingen</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-569" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-569"><a href="http://example.com/prijzen-omheining-offerte.html">Online offerte aanvragen</a></li>
    </ul></div>                                    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hbg">
    <div class="logo">
    <h4><a href="http://example.com" title="Tuin afsluitingen">Example.com</a></h4>
    <h5>Infosite over houten afsluitingen, korven, betonnen omheiningen, draadafsluiting met prijs advies.</h5>
    </div>
    <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/tuin-afsluitingen.jpg" width="661" height="165" alt="Tuin afsluitingen">
    </div>
    <div class="sb-slide">
    <div class="sb-toggle-left navbar-left" style="  cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;">
    <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/evotis1/images/nav_mob.png" class="" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add top positioning to your menu? IE - `.menu-toggle { position: fixed; top: 0; }`

NOTE - For mobile-only, you'll want to wrap the `menu-toggle` style in a media query such as:

```
@media (max-width: 479px) {
    .menu-toggle { 
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0; 
    }
}
```

Here's an example:

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
.menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
.hbg {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="togglemenuD">
      <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/evotis1/images/info_menu.png" class="image_disp" height="20px" width="20px">
    </div>
    <div class="menu_nav">
      <ul>
        <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
          <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-171" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-78 current_page_item menu-item-171"><a href="http://www.example.com/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-311" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-311"><a href="http://www.example.com/prijs-afsluiting.html">Prijs tuinafsluitingen</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-569" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-569"><a href="http://www.example.com/prijzen-omheining-offerte.html">Online offerte aanvragen</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hbg">
    <div class="logo">
      <h4><a href="http://www.example.com" title="Tuin afsluitingen">example.com</a></h4>
      <h5>Infosite over houten afsluitingen, korven, betonnen omheiningen, draadafsluiting met prijs advies.</h5>
    </div>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/tuin-afsluitingen.jpg" width="661" height="165" alt="Tuin afsluitingen">
  </div>
  <div class="sb-slide">
    <div class="sb-toggle-left navbar-left" style="  cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;">
      <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/evotis1/images/nav_mob.png" class="" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

NOTE - I've purposely given the body a height of `200vh` so you can scroll down and see that the menu stays fixed.

I'm also unsure exactly what part of the "header" you want to fix so I assumed the menu but I'm sure you can experiment with what works for you.

Comment: @Suraj your menu is collapsing because of its floated children... I'd suggest adding a clearfix to your CSS file: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ and adding the class `cf` to menu-toggle: `<div class="menu-toggle cf">`. You'll then be able to give menu-toggle `position: fixed` and it should work. That should amend your issue, if not, its helped you with a few headaches you might encounter down the line anyway...